# Building Ruby on Windows and conftest.c

Tags: ruby, windows, clang

I'm trying to build Ruby on Windows using clang. It builds just fine with the Microsoft compiler, but when I substitute clang, the configure stage fails with the following error:

```
C:\ruby-2.2.2\win32\build40>..\configure.bat
conftest.c(2,2) :  error:
#error
 ^
1 error generated.
clang-cl.exe: warning: Creating verconf.mk: 'linker' input unused
clang-cl.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I ../..'
clang-cl.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I ../../include'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

The next step would be to look at conftest.c to try to see what's going on, but a search across the entire hard disk finds no file of that name, and a log of all commands issued during configure doesn't shed much light either. What's up with this, and how can I get hold of a copy of conftest.c?

Further discussion at http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/433633?433552-433636

Comment: How did you get/build `clang`? Clang doesn't have a linking tool at the moment so if you used MSVC you'll need to have MSVC available to use it's linking tool.

Comment: @Azolo Yes, I built clang with Microsoft C++ 2013 (64 bit) which I also have available for the linker, nmake et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I had to guess, `conftest.c` is a temp file created by `nmake` to test the environment, and the problem is that `nmake` can't find `cl` (which should be replaced by `clang-cl`) when trying to run that test.

Check inside of the Ruby config script. I bet you'll find something that is causing `nmake` to look for `cl` instead of `clang-cl`. But I'm not sure.

I know that when building Ruby with `clang` from the `mingw64` tool chain that I had huge amounts of trouble getting any linker to work properly. It was pretty meh.

Comment: You're absolutely right that nmake is looking for cl. I've developed a solution to that problem: https://github.com/russellw/wic - as you can see from the error message, that much is working, clang-cl is indeed being called, but is barfing on conftest.c. Probably conftest.c is indeed a temporary file; what I need to know is how to get my hands on it so I can try to figure out why clang-cl is barfing.